# Sudden issue while deploying application in Openshift

Tags: java, tomcat, openshift

Yesterday I deployed my war in openshift using the usual command git push. But when I checked the url http://nrollin-nrollin.rhcloud.com, I am seeing the error HTTP Status 404 - The requested resource is not available. I have deployed the war many times but this is the first time I am seeing this error. I have even restarted the server but no luck. I searched down the cause in openshift forum also (https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/jbossas-application-the-requested-resource-is-not-available), but no solution to me as such yet. The app is running good in my local PC and is developed in Spring MVC and Hibernate.

Can anyone suggest me the cause of this issue? Or do I have to create app again..?

Below are the logs :

```
Jul 27, 2013 3:43:44 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.4.82.1-8080
Jul 27, 2013 3:43:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 5182 ms
Jul 27, 2013 3:43:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 27, 2013 3:43:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.37
Jul 27, 2013 3:43:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive ROOT.war
Jul 27, 2013 3:44:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jul 27, 2013 3:44:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
Jul 27, 2013 3:44:09 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.4.82.1-8080
Jul 27, 2013 3:44:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 25540 ms
```

Comment: Can you try a 'rhc app force-stop nrollin' at the command line. Then do a 'rhc app start nrollin'. Does that bring the application back?

Comment: No...same error is being displayed...I even restarted mysql server (in case that counts) but no result.. I wonder how come what can be the possible cause of such issue if the app is running fine in my local machine...and had been running properly till yesterday. I had done various push before that...!!

Comment: Check the logs.  'rhc ssh nrollin', then 'more ~/jbossews/logs/*' (depending on which cartridge you're using, the logs are in ~/<cart_type>/logs.  catalina.out or localhost*.out will have more details on the failure.  Also check your quota: 'quota -s'.

Comment: Nam Duong : I have added the logs in the question as you asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem in my local system yesterday but I resolved it by cleaning it along with its directory. I think the same would be needed for Openshift tomcat server.

Comment: "... by cleaning it along with its directory" > it ?